# Values not being posted from Partial View MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

For some reason my partial view is always returning null values to the controller. I've tried implementing this in several different ways (including editor templates) but here's my latest.

Basically I'm rendering a view with a jquery ui datepicker. When the user picks a date I then render my partial view. The partial view is being rendered correctly but when I submit the partial view it's returning a null object to the controller

**View Model:**

```
public class Attendance
{
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool Present { get; set; }

}
```

**Parent View:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Take Attendance";
}

<h2>Take Attendance</h2>

@Html.Hidden("GroupId", (int)ViewBag.GroupId)

<div>
@Html.Label("Select A Date")
@Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("attendanceDate",ViewBag.AttendanceDate)
                .OnSelect("attendanceDate.onSelect")
</div>

<div id="attendanceRecords">
</div>


@section scripts
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("../../Scripts/Views/TakeAttendance.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

**Partial View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<AT.Manager.Models.Attendance>

@using (Html.BeginForm("TakeAttendance", "Groups")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Present?</th>
        </tr>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++ )
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ElementAt(i).MemberName)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.ElementAt(i).Present)</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ElementAt(i).GroupId)</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ElementAt(i).MemberId)</td>
                <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ElementAt(i).RecordId)</td>
            </tr>                      
        }
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
}
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public ActionResult TakeAttendance(IEnumerable<Attendance> records)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var newRecords = records.Select(x => new da.Attendance() { Id = x.RecordId, GroupId = x.GroupId, MemberId = x.MemberId, Date = x.Date });
        AttendanceRepository attendanceRepo = new AttendanceRepository();
        newRecords.Each(x => attendanceRepo.InsertOrUpdate(x));
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try passing `IList<Attendance> records` to the view and then manipulate it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++ )
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model[i].MemberName)</td>
        <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model[i].Present)</td>
        // ...
    </tr>                      
}
```

Be sure to change `@model IEnumerable<AT.Manager.Models.Attendance>` to reflect the change of collection to `IList`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question may  have been a bit unclear, the problem I'm having is with the IEnumerable<Attendance> records parameter that's being passed to the controller. It's returning a null value so the code isn't even getting to the point of returning a view (or partial view). Can't figure out why my records object is null.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!! Been pulling my hair out over this one, still not completely clear as to why it works that way, but just glad it works!

Comment: Glad it helped. I think it has something to do with using (i) with IEnumberable inside the for loop. In fact, you could try using IEnumberable with the square brackets [i], just to see if it works.